# Adding description tag to PHP image gallery

Tags: php, html, css, image-gallery

I am trying add a descriptive tag under each image but most of the code is in PHP and i am not to familiar with how to program it without screwing up the whole structure. Here is the website: http://suncoastdeck.com/index.php?page=portfolio&start=0

Here is the code for the portfolio page:

```
<div class="content-box">
```

```
  <?

   //total number of images
   $total = 77;

   //max number of thumbnails per page
   $max = 9;

   //what image do we want to start from?
   $startcount = $_GET["start"];

   //if there is not a defined starting image, we start with the first
   if(empty($startcount))
    {
   $startcount = 0; 
  }

   //start off the loop at 1
   $loop = 1;


   //start the loop
   while($loop <= $max)
    {

   //for the picture labels
   $num = $startcount + $loop;

   if($num > $total)
    {
    $num = $num - 1;
    break;
    }

   // Add class="last" to every third list item
   if(is_int($num / 3))
   {
    $last = ' class="last"';
   }
   else
   {
     $last = "";
    }

   //the code for the image
   echo '

    <li'.$last.'><a href="images/portfolio/pic-'.$num.'.jpg" rel="milkbox[gall1]"><img src="images/portfolio/thumbs/pic-'.$num.'-thumb.jpg" width="256" height="138" alt="Thumbnail of image '.$num.'" /></a><div>'.$num.'</div></li>';


   //add 1 to the loop
   $loop++;
  }

  echo '</ul>';

  //Calculate the number of pages
  $total_pages = $total / $max;

   //clean it up
   if(!is_int($total_pages))
    {
   $total_pages = floor($total_pages) + 1;
   }

   //start the page count at 1
   $ploop = 1;

   echo '<hr /><div id="portfolio-wrap"><div id="pages">Page: ';

   while($ploop <= $total_pages)
    {
    $offset = ($ploop * $max) - $max;

    if($startcount == $offset)
     {
    echo '<span>'.$ploop.'</span>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<a href="index.php?page=portfolio&start='.$offset.'">'.$ploop.'</a>';
    }
    $ploop++;
    }

   echo '</div>';


   echo '<div id="portfolio-foot-left"><p>Displaying Images <strong>'.($startcount + 1).' - '.$num.'</strong> of <strong>'.$total.'</strong></p></div></div>';

  ?>
```

Pretty much what i want is to make section drop down a bit more where i can add in additional info about the pic. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need a database or else you can store your descriptions in a text file next to the image. What have you tried so far?

Basically you need to create a form that accepts the image name and caption, take the caption and write it to a file or database. Then when displaying the caption, you just add a `<div>` that reads from file with `file_get_contents()`. Why don't you copy the script to another directory and start experimenting? People probably won't write the whole thing for you ;)

Comment: i know about creating a image_gallery_description.txt file that have all the specific descriptions, but how extensive is the code that calls the specific .txt?